# How to redirect to URL Google sheets Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-redirect

Morning all.
I have a spreadsheet sheet which contains a URL.
I've been told that if I use the following I can create a script to a button in sheets instead of keeping a link visible:

```
function redirectToUrl (){
var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A4").get value();
window.location.href = url
}
```

This returns an error:
ReferenceError: window is not defined
redirectToUrl @Code:3

I have know Idea how to find what the error is or how to fix it to make the button launch the URL found in cell A4.

Debug shows variable:
Local
URL: the URL that exists in A4 (which when select in sheets opens new window)

Not experienced in scripts & just wanted a button to launch URL for my Adult IT class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a script like the one below, and add a button by inserting a drawing and then assigning the script to the drawing.

I'd advise checking out [Google Apps Script: A Beginners Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/) to get a basic understanding of how this works.

Script below should work, to see it in action make a copy of the sample file I created: [Open URL Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ppBGVb2KLnVhwfYD8bOYkHOvvZR8b_pnxRmjwI50tvY/edit?usp=sharing) and go to Extensions->Apps Script.

```
/**
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/
function openUrl() {
var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange("A4").getValue();
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
  '<!DOCTYPE html><html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function() 
  {google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; 
  a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1). 
  {window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
// Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to 
  open automatically.  Click below:<br/><a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" 
  onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(55);google.script.host.setWidth(410) 
  </script>'
  +'</html>')
.setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening ..." );
}
```